# tensorflow_datasets version compatible with tensorflow 1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow 1.15 in my code and I would like to use `tensorflow_datasets`. I installed the last version of `tensorflow_datasets` but it seems to be in conflict with my version of tf. The actual message when trying to import `tensorflow_datasets` was:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

> ImportError: This version of TensorFlow Datasets requires TensorFlow
> version >= 2.1.0; Detected an installation of version 1.15.0. Please
> upgrade TensorFlow to proceed.

So, obviously a newer version of tf (like one >= 2.1.0) would work but I want to keep my version of tf and instead use a previous version of `tensorflow_datasets`.

I tried to find this information in github repository but to no avail.

So, is there a version available and if so which is the latest one compatible with tf 1.15?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The support of TF `1.15` was dropped on the passage to TFDS `4.0.0`. (See [commit a2fe67c415a7af740fd7ec810b79c9fa80f29516](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/commit/a2fe67c415a7af740fd7ec810b79c9fa80f29516)).

The latest version of `TFDS` that support TF `1.15` is the `3.2.1`.

```
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 12:42:55) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'1.15.0'
>>> import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
>>> tfds.__version__
'3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the below command for TF 1.15

```
pip install tensorflow_datasets==3.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the absolute latest, but TFDS `2.1.0` will work with TF `1.15`.